# how to find the original directed graph?

Tags: graph, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

I was thinking on a homework question given to me, it is as follows: 
 If you are given with a BFS and DFS traversal of a directed( or un-directed graph), 
how would you find the original graph ?
Is it possible in either case?

thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, it is not possible, since BFS and DFS produce a tree, and tree has |V|-1 edges. So, in these two trees you have at most 2|V|-2 different edges, and original graph can have up to |V|(|V|-1) edges for directed, and |V|(|V|-1)/2 for undirected graph.